# Check if a list of strings contains one of several specific pairs of strings

Tags: python, list, tuples, any

The motivation behind this is a card game, where I want to determine whether or not a 5-card hand contains certain combinations of specific cards, and those combinations are written in a list.

More generally, say I have a list of strings:

```
hand = ["apple", "apple", "banana", "cabbage", "durian"]
```

and I also have a list of tuples:

```
combos = [
    ["apple", "banana"],
    ["banana", "lettuce"],
    ["banana", "pear"],
    ["cabbage", "cabbage"]
]
# code returns true because "apple" and "banana" are in the original list
```

I want to determine whether any of the pairs of strings in "combos" show up in my original list. This is complicated by the fact that the same item can appear multiple times, both in my original list and as valid "combos".

A naive way to do this is checking one item at a time in my original list, finding every combo containing that item, and then seeing if I have the other combo item. I'm wondering if there is a more concise, elegant way to do this.

Comment: A bit more info needed. Do they need to appear beside eachother? If the combo is "banana", "banana", does it need to appear twice in the original list?

Comment: start with `for combo in combos: if all(c in hand for c in combo): ...` - the look into set.intersect() and check if `set(combo).intersect(hand)==set(combo)` - if you want to also check dupes of the same thing- compare that Counter(hand) includes same/more then Counter(combo) - do that with sets as well. But that are all just optimizations - the first loopy approach if totally fine to perform for your card game ...

Comment: @eligolf Order doesn't matter, but quantity does. So if combos contains `["banana", "banana", "cabbage"]`, then the original list contains that combo only if it has 2 bananas and 1 cabbage (but it does not matter what order).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it using any() on a list comprehension:

```
hand = ["apple", "apple", "banana", "cabbage", "durian"]
combos = [
    ["apple", "banana"],
    ["banana", "lettuce"],
    ["banana", "pear"],
    ["cabbage", "cabbage"]
]

match = any( a in hand and hand.count(b)>(a==b) for a,b in combos )

print(match) # True
```

To know which one matched:

```
matches = [ (a,b) for a,b in combos if a in hand and hand.count(b)>(a==b)]

print(*matches)
# ('apple', 'banana')
```

You could also do it  a bit more concicely using the Counter class:

```
from collections import Counter
comboCounts = list(map(Counter,combos))

handCounts  = Counter(hand)
match       = any(not combo-handCounts for combo in comboCounts)

print(match) # True
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
def check_combos(combos, hand):
    for combo in combos:
        index = []
        for item in combo:
            if item in hand and hand.index(item)not in index:
                index.append(hand.index(item))
        if len(index) == len(combo):
            return True 
    return False
```

You check each item in `combo` and find where in `hand` it appears, to be sure you don't find the same item in `hand` again. If all items in `combo` match an index in `hand` you return True (or whatever you need to return). If you go through all combos and none of them matches you return False.